# Remove image in jQuery Mobile li

Tags: jquery, image, listview, jquery-mobile

I want an icon to be toggled in a jQuery listview each time the user clicks a line.

[Here is the complete source code](http://jsfiddle.net/Maxbester/KkRK4/1/).

The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
$(this).remove('img');
```

I also tried:

```
$(this).remove('icon');
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(this).find('img').remove();
```

[Here's the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7tXz/).

Comment: Ok thanks. But according to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), my version should work. Do you understand why it doesn't?

Comment: It's certainly an odd behaviour, it would seem `remove()` is functioning correctly, but as [this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7816) shows it's confusing.

Comment: @Maxbester, you are misinterpreting the docs. From the docs `$('div').remove('.hello'); means remove the `div` which has `.hello`. The argument acts as `filter` (not `selector`). Your code `$(this).remove('img');` means from the array of `$(this)` , filter the element which has `img` tag and remove that only.